# switch hosts-file during win7 boot process

Tags: windows-7, boot, hosts-file

I have 2 hosts files on my win7 machine that i switch manually (.bat file run as administrator) when i'm either in the company vpn or connected to the comany network directly.

What i would want is an option at boot-time to be able to make this selection. Preferebly a selection that has a default and a timeout.

How would i do that?

Comment: why do you need switch *hosts* file when you connected/disconnected VPN ?

Comment: i can only reach some of the servers via a vpn-ip-address when i'm connected over vpn. When i'm directly connected to the network those ips are not available (and vice versa). There is no DNS service that would help me here.

Comment: are you using hostname instead of IP address to access the servers?

Comment: yes, i do that to transparently access a svn-repo e.g.

Comment: would you like to connect the SVN server with it's public IP address no matter whether you're connected the VPN or not ? (so that you don't need to switch hosts file)

Comment: there is no "public" address. there's one in the vpn, and one in the company-lan. i'd rather access the server via a name, but if re-routing one of the ips works, i'll go with that.

Comment: you're saying your SVN server has different IP addresses when you're in VPN and in LAN, if so, is the LAN-ip-address accessible when you're in VPN?

Comment: no, it's not, unfortunately.

Comment: Switching hosts file during boot time seems impossible or too hard (maybe write a driver), how about switch hosts file when you logon: edit your .bat, add a procedure to ask for a choise. then put the .bat file to startup folder.